# LINQ to nHibernate - translating SQL "NOT IN" expression to LINQ

Tags: linq-to-nhibernate, sql-to-linq-conversion

I tried to translate SQL "NOT IN" expression to LINQ, and I found that I should use the "Contains" option.
I have 2 tables:

```
ProductsGroups         Products                    
--------------         ---------    
id                     product_id    
product_id             product_name
```

My queries looks like this:

```
var innerQuery = from pg in Session.Query<ProductsGroups>       
select pg.product_id;     

var Query = from p in Session.Query<Products>                        
where !innerQuery.Contains(p.product_id)                        
select new {p.product_id, p.product_name};
```

But the sql that nHibernate generates is wrong:

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name    
from Products p    
where not (exists (select product_id                       
from ProductsGroups pg                   
where p.product_id = pg.id))
```

**The "where" clause is not on the right field, it compares product_id to progucts group id.** 
Does anybody knows how can I solve it?

The solution that I found for meanwhile is to convert first query to list, and then
use this list in second query:

```
var innerQuery = (from pg .....).ToList();
```

Then, the nHibernate translates the "Contains" expression to "NOT IN", as I want:

```
select p.product_id, p.product_name    
from Products p    
where not (p.product_id in (1,2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think you're running into a problem b/c contains determines if an element is in the collection by "using the default equality comparer." (MS documentation) I assume your productgroup mapping specifies it's Id as the Id property. So from nHibernate's perspective that is the value to use to determine equality.